# predefine bins in geom_histogram

Tags: r, ggplot2

How do I pre-define bins for the histogram? For e.g.

predefine_bin_edges <- seq(0, 10, 1)

Can someone please use this predefine bin edges to update the example.

Edited later -
Also, Is there a way to include the extreme points, that are outside the binrange, in the corner bins for a complete picture of data distribution.

```
library(tidyverse)

# data
x <- rnorm(n = 1000, mean = 5, sd = 3)
tbl <- tibble(x)

# geom_histogram()
ggplot(data = tbl,
       aes(x = x)) + 
  geom_histogram()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean like this?

```r
library(tidyverse)

# data
x <- rnorm(n = 1000, mean = 5, sd = 3)
tbl <- tibble(x)

# geom_histogram()
ggplot(data = tbl,
       aes(x = x)) + 
  geom_histogram(breaks = seq(0, 10, 1))
```

[image]

I don't think there is an argument to geom histogram that can include the values outside the range in the corner bins. However, you can squish the data at the `aes()` level.

```r
ggplot(data = tbl,
       aes(x = pmax(pmin(x, 10), 0))) + 
  geom_histogram(breaks = seq(0, 10, 1))
```

Or if you're uncomfortable with that, you can set the limits + oob arguments in the scale.

```r
ggplot(data = tbl,
       aes(x = x)) + 
  geom_histogram(breaks = seq(0, 10, 1)) +
  scale_x_continuous(limits = c(0, 10),
                     oob = scales::oob_squish)
```

Comment: thanks, but does the corner bins hold all the points (x) outside the pre-define bin range ?

Comment: No the datapoints outside the breaks aren't included in the plot at all.

Comment: Is there a way to include them in the corner bins for a complete picture of data distribution

Comment: Thanks, that was helpful!